# Is it possible to conditionally show some text in pdfMake library?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using pdfmake for generating a pdf format report.

```
 const docDefination = {
    content: [{text: 'some long text ...', style: ''}]
 }

 pdfMake.createPdf(docDefination).open()
```

So my question is if the text gets to large (which may happen because text will be dynamic) and it breaks into a separate page is it possible to show a text like 'Continue reading' on the second page through some conditioning.

Ps. I don't want to make the pdf page unbreakable I just want to show some texts conditionally to the second page if the text is so long that needs a second page.

Answer (score 0):

2022: PDFMake doesn't have such a feature.

As a workaround, if you handle manually the page breaks (by counting how much space is taken by each element), you'll know when your 'page overflow' event happens, allowing you to add the 'continue reading' message.

Cheers